# Interesting (weird) result in a Swift computation

Tags: swift, double, arithmetic-expressions

While I was playing and testing various things with `SwiftUI`.
I found this bizarre situation. It is I guess related to the limit value that `Double` can handle, but anyway I thought it was weird enough to make a post. And hopefully someone can explain exactly what is happening or let me know where I made a mistake.

It seems like any odd value for t in the following code will cause the same kind of trouble.

```
let v:Double = 13082761331670030, t:Double = 1
var u:Double

u = v - t;
u += t;

if u == v {print("All is right.")}
else {
    print("This is weird. We now have:")
    print("v = \(String(format: "%.0f",v)) and u = \(String(format: "%.0f",u))")
}
```

Executing the code leads to:

```
u != v
```

Comment: Representable floating point numbers are not uniformly distributed. They become sparser and sparser as you increase in magnitude. There is simply no real number that rounds to 13082761331670029 that is also representable by `Double`, so u + 1 is still 13082761331670028.

Comment: try setting `let v: Double = 13082761331670031` (+1 over what you have) and you'll see a warning from XCode. `Double` lacks precision due to limited number of bits to represent the significant digits

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: Relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2094022/why-does-floating-point-numbers-have-uneven-spacing-on-the-number-line

Comment: Here’s a simpler example: `let v: Double = 13082761331670031`. Now print `v`. You’re simply exceeding what can represented accurately in a 64 bit floating type.

Comment: Right! An even simpler case. The point is the same.